# Callbacks from C code using C++ code?

Tags: c++, callback, namespaces

I am using a driver written in pure C. It has some callbacks registered to it. When those are called they will interact with C++ code.

I tried to access functions in a namespace in the callback but that have me an error which made me think they can't call C++ code which makes a lot of sense I guess.
But then I realized I was interacting with C++ classes with no problem.

So is it allowed for a callback executed in C code to call C++ specific functioanlity like namespaces and classes?

Comment: gotta recognize the symbol mangling differences.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `#include` the header as a C file:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "c_file.h"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So is it allowed for a callback executed in C code to call C++ specific functioanlity like namespaces and classes?

Yes. The usual solution to this is to create an opaque (void*) object that holds the pointer of your class, and a set of callbacks declared as `extern "C"` in your C++ code, that receive the `void *`, `reinterpret_cast` it to your class pointer and call the appropriate functions.

If you do not need classes remembered for your callbacks, you can dispense of the `void*` and the `reinterpret_cast` stuff but the callbacks in C++ still need to be declared as `extern "C"` for the C code to be able to call them.